# Getting id with Where clause

Tags: laravel, get, notifications, where-clause, middleware

I have a question. Do anyone know how to take the id id this case

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {   
        if($request->has('id')) {
            $notification = auth()->user()->unreadNotifications()->where('I need put something here', $request->id)->first();
            if($notification) {
                $notification->markAsRead();
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

My table structule is like 
Id: 4
Notifiable_type App\User 
Notifiable_id 1
Data : {"evaluation_id":1} !!! and here is the point the $request->id in my case is equal to evaluation_id and I also need to take the evaluation_id from inside the data column to compare them and get the ID

Comment: can you tell more about your `Data : {"evaluation_id":1}` how you are accessing it here? based on that only I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly.

you need to compare data's evaluation_id with the $request->id?

if that:

```
     $notification = auth()->user()->unreadNotifications()
->where('Data->evaluation_id', $request->id)->first();
```